# HiveError (HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Slug. Did you forget to register an adapter?)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a very simple app to stream anime from a popular anime site, however I have a hard time working with Hive.

I'm trying to fetch all anime from anime site and then save it to cache in Hive. However I ran into issue, which blocks my development. I registered an adapter, but Hive is telling me that I didn't.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix it?

## My code

### lib/main.dart

```dart
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:twist_go/pages/nav_screen.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US')],
    path: 'lib/assets/translations',
    fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
    child: TwistGO(),
  ));
}

class TwistGO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      home: NavScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

## models/anime_all.dart

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'anime_all.g.dart';

List<AnimeAll> animeAllFromJson(String str) =>
    List<AnimeAll>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => AnimeAll.fromJson(x)));

String animeAllToJson(List<AnimeAll> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class AnimeAll extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  final int id;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String title;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String altTitle;

  @HiveField(3)
  final int season;

  @HiveField(4)
  final int ongoing;

  @HiveField(5)
  final int hbId;

  @HiveField(6)
  final DateTime createdAt;

  @HiveField(7)
  final DateTime updatedAt;

  @HiveField(8)
  final int hidden;

  @HiveField(9)
  final int malId;

  @HiveField(10)
  final Slug slug;

  AnimeAll({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.altTitle,
    this.season,
    this.ongoing,
    this.hbId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.hidden,
    this.malId,
    this.slug,
  });

  factory AnimeAll.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AnimeAll(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        altTitle: json["alt_title"] == null ? null : json["alt_title"],
        season: json["season"],
        ongoing: json["ongoing"],
        hbId: json["hb_id"] == null ? null : json["hb_id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
        hidden: json["hidden"],
        malId: json["mal_id"] == null ? null : json["mal_id"],
        slug: Slug.fromJson(json["slug"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "alt_title": altTitle == null ? null : altTitle,
        "season": season,
        "ongoing": ongoing,
        "hb_id": hbId == null ? null : hbId,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "hidden": hidden,
        "mal_id": malId == null ? null : malId,
        "slug": slug.toJson(),
      };
}

class Slug {
  Slug({
    this.id,
    this.slug,
    this.animeId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  int id;
  String slug;
  int animeId;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  factory Slug.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Slug(
        id: json["id"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        animeId: json["anime_id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "slug": slug,
        "anime_id": animeId,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

### models/anime_all.g.dart

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'anime_all.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class AnimeAllAdapter extends TypeAdapter<AnimeAll> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  AnimeAll read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return AnimeAll(
      id: fields[0] as int,
      title: fields[1] as String,
      altTitle: fields[2] as String,
      season: fields[3] as int,
      ongoing: fields[4] as int,
      hbId: fields[5] as int,
      createdAt: fields[6] as DateTime,
      updatedAt: fields[7] as DateTime,
      hidden: fields[8] as int,
      malId: fields[9] as int,
      slug: fields[10] as Slug,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, AnimeAll obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(11)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.id)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.title)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.altTitle)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.season)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.ongoing)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.hbId)
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..write(obj.createdAt)
      ..writeByte(7)
      ..write(obj.updatedAt)
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..write(obj.hidden)
      ..writeByte(9)
      ..write(obj.malId)
      ..writeByte(10)
      ..write(obj.slug);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is AnimeAllAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

### services/net/anime_twist.dart

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:twist_go/models/anime_all.dart';
import 'package:twist_go/.env.dart';
import 'package:twist_go/models/anime_single.dart';
import 'package:twist_go/models/anime_sources.dart';

class AnimeTwistApiService {
  static const String _baseUrl = 'https://twist.moe/api/anime/';
  var _headers = {'x-access-token': EnvironmentVariables.token};

  Future<List<AnimeAll>> getAllAnime() async {
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      _baseUrl,
      headers: _headers,
    );

    return animeAllFromJson(response.body);
  }

  Future<AnimeSingle> getSingleAnime(String slug) async {
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      _baseUrl + slug,
      headers: _headers,
    );

    return animeSingleFromJson(response.body);
  }

  Future<List<AnimeSources>> getAnimeSources(String slug) async {
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      _baseUrl + slug + '/sources',
      headers: _headers,
    );

    return animeSourcesFromJson(response.body);
  }
}
```

### services/db/anime_twist_cache.dart

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:twist_go/models/anime_all.dart';
import 'package:twist_go/services/net/anime_twist.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;

class AnimeTwistCacheService {
  Future<void> cacheAllAnime() async {
    final _appDocumentDir =
        await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(_appDocumentDir.path);
    Hive.registerAdapter<AnimeAll>(AnimeAllAdapter());

    Hive.openBox('all-anime');
    final AnimeTwistApiService _animeTwistApiService = AnimeTwistApiService();

    List<AnimeAll> allAnime = await _animeTwistApiService.getAllAnime();

    Hive.box('all-anime').add(allAnime);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out the issue here, You have a custom-defined data-type named Slug

```
slug: fields[10] as Slug,
```

Make a new dart class and create an adapter for slug as you created before which will look something like this:

```
class SlugAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Slug>{
   @override
  read(BinaryReader reader) {
   // TODO: implement read
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement typeId
  int get typeId => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, obj) {
   // TODO: implement write
  }
}
```

and then register this adapter in hive initialization:

```
Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
Hive
  ..init(dir.path)
  ..registerAdapter(SlugAdapter());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your adapter (*models/anime_all.dart*) you have field `slug` with type `Slug` so you have to create and register an adapter to the `Slug` class as well.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Same as `AnimeAll` adapter but with `Slug` class fields and unique `HiveType` annotation (for example: if you have only `AnimeAll` adapter with typeId = 0, you can use `@HiveType(typeId: 1)`)

Comment: @szakes1, have you managed this? If not, just let me know :)

Answer (score -2):

you need register model on init Hive fuction add this line whit your modelAdapter them generate "yourmodel".g.dart file.

```
Hive.registerAdapter(YourModelAdapter());
```